# Run pre-commit hooks when using magit, poetry, and tramp

Tags: magit, python, tramp, remote, vc

This is an emacs & magit version of the following question, with an added twist.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72839263/access-python-interpreter-in-vscode-version-controll-when-using-pre-commit

The self-answer there (by Mehdi) also works for me: just start emacs as a subprocess of poetry (with `poetry run emacs -nw` or similar) and poetry will set up the PATH which emacs inherits, and everything works fine.

The twist is that I also want to work with remote repos, via tramp. Understandably, poetry knows nothing about emacs and tramp, so although magit itself magitally works over tramp, my pre-commit hooks which are managed by poetry do not work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... `git` runs the pre-commit hook, not Emacs; so why would Emacs need to know anything about the PATH required by a git hook?

Comment: My guess is that your pre-commit hook is failing *in general* without a supporting PATH, and so you're wanting Emacs to call `git` with a custom environment to get around that.  I think adding to `tramp-remote-path` will handle that.  Alternatively you could update the pre-commit hook so that it knows where to find the things it depends upon.

Comment: The problem is that the PATH is managed by poetry. Those directories have random-like hash based names, different for each project (and even different for each branch if the branches have different python dependencies). Manually setting up that in emacs for each new project/branch is quite out of the question.

Comment: Even before I asked here, I'd known of one very ugly & hacky "solution". Have a trivial shell script somewhere that just execs `poetry run git "$@"`. Set `magit-git-executable` to that script. But looking for something a bit more tolerable, and I have not tested if it would work across tramp ie. would tramp find the script on the remote?

Comment: It will if it's in one of the `tramp-remote-path` directories.  Use `magit-remote-git-executable` though.

Comment: You can also set `magit-remote-git-executable` to an absolute path to the script, of course, in which case you don't need to touch `tramp-remote-path` at all.

Comment: Btw, I think "even different for each branch" makes it *significantly* less practical to do anything more than that on the Emacs side, so I'd just do that and, if `poetry` is something which is slow to execute, then make your wrapper script only call it conditionally (i.e. if a `git commit` command is actually being used, as you don't care about `pre-commit` hooks in other circumstances).

Comment: Maybe raise a bug report with the `poetry` people though -- if it's "managing" git hooks in such a way that they don't work unless you're doing other stuff too, then potentially it could do a better job of the "managing" so that this wasn't a problem in the first place.

Comment: Oh, and if your wrapper script is *also* called `git` then of course you want to make that `poetry run git "$@"` isn't just going to call it recursively.  Either mess with PATH in the wrapper, or tell poetry the absolute path to the real `git`.  If the wrapper is *only* for Emacs though, I expect there's no reason to name it `git`.

Comment: I didn't know about `magit-remote-git-executable`. It's not documented in the magit info file. But it's there, and now that I know about it I'll probably use it.